# Is it bad practice to use trigger() for duplicate event handling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often use jQuery `.trigger()` for handling duplicate events.

For example, if I have a widget that has four buttons for navigation (up, down, left, right), and an event handler is bound on each button like:

```
$('#up').on('click', function() {
    // move up
    ...
});
```

So far, the widget works well, and now I want to add keyboard shortcuts on `up/down/left/right arrow key` such that each button works exactly the same as when `up/down/left/right button` is pressed.

In such a case, I often use `.trigger()` to make the keyboard shortcuts work as wrappers of those buttons.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    // up arrow key
    if (e.keyCode == 38) $('#up').trigger('click');
    ...
});
```

Is it bad practice to use `.trigger()` as such?

I think it is very handy when I handle a library as a black box. If there are already some buttons to help control the library, I can use the library's functionality by triggering click events on those buttons even without knowing the library's API.

Comment: I would simply make a callback function and then call it wherever I want in the code, instead of triggering a 'click'.

Comment: If this functionality is something that you're adding on top of the widget, yes, trigger would be an appropriate way of doing it. If this is functionality that you're adding to the widget itself, there's probably a better way to handle it.

Comment: You are using `trigger` in the right way. You can also use the shortcut `$('#up').click();` if you prefer

Comment: I would say it is not the best practice. If later the ui is changed and it is decided that the buttons on the page should have another `id` or should be removed, but the shortcut with keyboard should remain, then you need to explicit document that behavior so this relation is known. Personally i would either call the same callback function, or trigger a custom event like `x-shortcut` on the `html` element, passing the shortcut information with the event, that way you are independent of the html structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really bad practice, but there are other ways to do it, even if they aren't necessarily better, like :

```
$('#up').on('click', clickHandler);

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 38) clickHandler();
});

function clickHandler() {
    //do stuff
}
```

or

```
$(document).on('click keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'keydown' && e.which === 38) {
         // do stuff for key
    }else if (e.type == 'click' && e.target.id == 'up') {
         // do stuff when click on #up
    }
});
```

It's opinion based I guess, but I prefer the first one, with the external function you call, over triggering the event itself, even if they do the same thing.

I wouldn't use the last one, as that is delegated and triggers on any click etc.

Answer (score 3):

Some people would say that it's bad practice, some would say it's OK, however it may not be the easiest code to understand.  Instead, I would suggest defining a corresponding function and then calling it from the triggers.  For example:

```
function doUp() {
    //your code for handling "up" functionality
}

$('#up').on('click', doUp);

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    // up arrow key
    if (e.keyCode == 38) doUp();
    ...
});
```

And similarly for other keys/buttons.

This way you have a single place where you put your logic and then you call it from wherever it's necessary.